# Missing GTK3 function

Tags: gcc, gtk3, autoconf, automake

I'm failing to use a bootstrap for GTK3 using autoconf and automake. I'm following [this](https://ptomato.github.io/advanced-gtk-techniques/html/real-life-app-setup.html) guide.

I have installed gtk3 with: `sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev`

`pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` returns: `3.22.30`

`pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` returns:

```
-pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
```

as you can see there is a lot of repetitions (don't know if that's okay).

both `autoreconf - i` and `configure` returns without any error.

`make` call gcc with:

```
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"Vacolina\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"vacolina\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"Vacolina\ 1\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"my-email@gmail.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"vacolina\" -DVERSION=\"1\" -I.    -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -g -O2 -MT hello-world.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/hello-world.Tpo -c -o hello-world.o hello-world.c
```

and error out with some missing functions:

- gtk_window_set_child
- gtk_window_destroy

(remember this is just a basic bootstrap code, so it's using very few functions by now)

I've searched every `.h` file in `/usr/include/gtk-3.0` and indeed none of them define those function.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I've found information that the order of parameters to `gcc` is important. So, why original guide works? And how to tell automake to invert command order?

Comment: The hello-world.c in the guide does not use those functions.  Have you modified the provided hello-world.c ?  BTW, the functions you mentioned are part of GTK4, but not GTK3.

Comment: So on further inspection... the 'automake' page apparently instructs to download a hello-world.c from off-site, which has updated to GTK4.  I believe the tutorial is poorly laid out, and at least this portion of it is effectively broken as far as GTK3 is concerned.

Comment: `gtk_window_set_child` and `gtk_window_destroy` are gtk4 api. For gtk3 use `gtk_container_add` and `gtk_widget_destroy` respectively

Comment: @whydoubt you are obviously right Sr. I searched for a GTK3 hello-world in another page and it works now. I have wasted so much time guessing my libraries were wrong and never thought about this. Thank you!